# How to change setting of datepicker inside of datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I change the setting of one datepicker inside of other datepicker?

**This is what I tried**

```
$('#from_date').datepicker({
            autoclose:true,
        }).on('changeDate', function() {
            $('#to_date').datepicker({
                minDate: $('#from_date').val(),
            });
        });
```

**I also tried this**

```
$('#from_date').datepicker({
                autoclose:true,
            }).on('changeDate', function() {
                $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#from_date').val())
            });
```

I want to disable the date before the `from_date` value if the `from_date` date is changed.

Thanks for the help

Comment: There is no `autoclose` option in `jquery-ui-datepicker`. Make sure which one are you using

Comment: Okay thanks. But that's not my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`setStartDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setstartdate) method

**Note: [jquery-ui-datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) are different**

```
$('#from_date').datepicker({
     autoclose:true,
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
     $('#to_date').datepicker('setStartDate', e.date)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `option` api.

Use it like this:

example:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
```

With your code:

```
$('#to_date').datepicker( "option", "minDate", $('#from_date').val())
```